# Find range of values for p in equation of circle

Tags: circles

Can somebody please check my working with the following question:

> Given the equation ${x^2 + y^2 - 2px - 4py + 3p + 2 = 0}$ represents a
>   circle, determine a range of values for p.

I don't think I can use the discriminant because there are y values so I can use:

${g^2 + f^2 - c > 0}$

g = -p

f = -2p

c = 3p + 2

${(-p)^2 + (-2p)^2  - 3p + 2 > 0}$

=> ${p^2 +4p^2 -3p + 2 > 0}$

=> ${5p^2 -3p + 2 > 0}$

I thought I would then find values for p and display them like ${p_1 < p < p_2}$

I was going to use the quadratic formula:

=> ${{3 \pm \sqrt{(-3)^2 - 4(5)(2)}}\over 5}$

But the discriminant is a negative number so I don't think I am on the right path.

Comment: = symbol not present in "equation"!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Typo in equation of circle, there should be equality symbol "=" somewhere in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $-3p-2$ rather than just $-3p+2$ and you are on right path.

Comment: Ah right, I did not multiply the negative to both parts of the term

Comment: I suggest you to make brackets because many a times i do the same mistake!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$(x-p)^2+(y-2p)^2=5p^2-3p-2=(5p+2)(p-1)$$ which needs to be positive

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: So my answer would be -2/5 < p < 1?

Comment: What method of factorisation did  you use to get there?

Comment: @dagda1, How have you found $$g^2+f^2-c>0$$  and $$(x-a)(x-b)>0, a<b\implies$$ either $x>b$  or $x<a$

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand.  I though the range of values for p would be whatever the quadratic expression factorises into.

Comment: @dagda1, As the equation of a circle : $$(x-g)^2+(y-f)^2=f^2+g^2-c$$  I tried to complete the squares